# Add images to drawable-* folder in run-time

Tags: android

How can I add images to drawable-* folder in run-time?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. And if you could it would still be an incorrect approach.

Answer (score 6):

you can not. The res folder has to be filled up at compile time in order to let the compile generate the R.java file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't as said by @blackbelt. But you can still generate it at runtime :

If you have some images with different resolution as indicated by a suffix like :

- close-ldpi.png
- close-mdpi.png
- close-hdpi.png

You can do something like

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    String fileName = "close";
    String fileSuffix = "";
    String fileExtension = ".png";
    int dpi = Math.round( metrics.density * 160 );
    if ( dpi<= 120/*DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW*/) {
        fileSuffix = "-ldpi";
    } else if ( dpi<= 160/*DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM*/) {
        fileSuffix = "-mdpi";
    } else if ( dpi<= 240/*DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH*/) {
        fileSuffix = "-hdpi";
    } else if ( dpi<= 320/*DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH*/) {
        fileSuffix = "-hdpi";
    }//else

    Drawable crossDrawable = new BitmapDrawable( getClass().getResourceAsStream( fileName + fileSuffix + fileExtension ) ); 
    //getContext().getResources().getDrawable( android.R.drawable.btn_dialog );
    crossImage.setImageDrawable(crossDrawable);
```